# multithreading bug race condition problem

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition

I am trying to make my character person running on a 2D grid using threads. I change the location (person's location on grid) to be atomicReference and change its getter and setter to be atomic method. However, when program is executing, my character is moving wrong directions (moving forward a few steps and backward a few steps). I wonder what went wrong, assuming the pathfinding is fine to use?

is it because the print method is not atomic? How should I change a method to be atomic? or is there another way to solve the race condition bug?

```
public abstract class Person {
    Optional<Color> skinColor;
    AtomicReference<Cell> location;
    Move move;


public Person(Cell location, Move move){
    this.location = new AtomicReference<>(location);
    this.skinColor = Optional.empty();
    this.move = move;
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
        Cell temp=location.get();
        if (skinColor.isPresent()) {
            g.setColor(skinColor.get());
            g.fillOval(temp.x + temp.width / 4, temp.y + temp.height / 4, temp.width / 2, temp.height / 2);
            g.drawOval(temp.x + temp.width / 4, temp.y + temp.height / 4, temp.width / 2, temp.height / 2);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
}

public void setLocationOf(Cell loc){
        location.set(loc);
}

public Cell getLocationOf(){
        return location.get();
}

public void setMove(Move move){
    this.move = move;
}

public List<Step> autoMoves() {
    return move.pathPathing(this);

}
```

}

Comment: I don't see a `print` method or a `move` method in the code that you posted. Please post a [mcve] (note: all of MCV and E are important, but what you posted is not Complete - we can't run the code to reproduce your problem)

Comment: Based on the code provided it is really hard to tell what is wrong. I assume that in your threads you first getLocation and then based on that create a move. Those are two distinct operations and they should be put in a synchronized block/method. It doesn't change much if they are atomic on their own.